# Read Data from USB RFID Reader for Android

Tags: android, rfid

I am connecting USB RFID reader to Android Tablet using OTG cable.
Data from RFID tag is directly written into notepad, but I can't access the device from Android code.  RFID reader is not recognized as USB by app.

Anyone has faced similar problem. 
I need to get the data in Android app.

Comment: So the RFID reader emulates a keyboard?  If so I would expect the same behavior on the android device.  So you wouldn't have anything to access it via code as it's a keyboard.

Comment: Unless you have root on the device and can get the system to ignore it so that it becomes available to the USB Host APIs, you will probably have to acquire the data as keyboard data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the input. I was trying to solve this problem from past few days.

I solved the problem by adding a edit text in my app and now the input 
from RFID reader directly comes into edit text.

Comment: I am facing same issue, instead of getting input from reader at textbox, I want like to read programmatically. Let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: I was getting the input directly in textbox as soon as card was scanned. Not programmatically.

Comment: Solution was posted by @DhavalPatel I dont get it why you marked this as solution.

Answer (score 5):

After research I have found that USB RFID Reader which is Keyboard Interface type is going to work as Keyboard input interface device when attached to Android OS, and therefor not able to read using API. (This is the how RFID manufacture has design that type of Reader)

However there are Read & Write type of Read which can be read and write using API. Reader manufacture must have to provide API kit to in order to read/write data from Reader.

Comment: Have you further infrmation about this topic? F.e. how to access the input value by the scanner as keyboard input? I want to have the information from the scanner in my android app.

Comment: @YvonneMarggraf did you manage to figure this one out? Would appreciate any tips!

Comment: More or less. I used a Chainway scanner and tried to read the Chinese docu in the English version... It was readable but it took a lot of time. The data were send in a special object and I had to divide between UTC and TIP to get the data I needed for the Android app.

Comment: My tipp to find the clue for your problem: Use the docu of your device or OS and look for the data you want to have and try to get the whole object first, and then try to smallerise this up to the value you need. I did it the same way with Try-And-Error-Methods.